# Send form fields of type name="foo[1][bar]" as JSON to Node

Tags: jquery, json, node.js

I'd like to send (POST) a dynamically  growing form as JSON to NodeJs through jQuery/ajax. The perfect result in Node would be a data structure like

```
{
servers: [
    1: {
        name: someServer,
        host: someserver.tld,
        port: 80
    },
    2: {
        name: someOtherServer,
        host: someotherserver.tld,
        port: 8080
    }
]
}
```

What I've tried now is a form looking like

```
<input name="servers[1][name]">
<input name="servers[1][host]">
<input name="servers[1][port]">

<input name="servers[2][name]">
<input name="servers[2][host]">
<input name="servers[2][port]">
```

And then send it using `JSON.stringify(form.serializeArray()`

This however does not work - as the body in Node looks like:

```
body: [
   { name: 'server[0][name]', value: 'ucbuild02' },
   { name: 'server[0][host]', value: 'ucbuild02.udac.se' },
   { name: 'server[0][port]', value: '2376' },
   { name: 'server[1][name]', value: 'ucaccapp01' },
   { name: 'server[1][host]', value: 'ucaccapp01.udac.se' },
   { name: 'server[1][port]', value: '2376' },
   { name: 'server[2][name]', value: 'ucaccapp03' } 
],
```

Is this a problem with how I format my form, how I serialize it, or how I parse it in Node? The data is sent as JSON - verified by the request header as `application/json`

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in function that I know of that could do what you want directly, but a potential solution would be to use delimiters in your form names, instead of array notation, like this:

```
<input name="servers-1-name">
<input name="servers-1-host">
<input name="servers-1-port">

<input name="servers-2-name">
<input name="servers-2-host">
<input name="servers-2-port">
```

then walk over the form array, splitting the names and forming your js object.

```
var formData = form.serializeArray();
var output = { servers: [] };
for (var x = 0, len = formData.length; x < len; x++) {
     var namePieces = formData[x].name.split('-');
     var number = parseInt(namePieces[1]);
     var name = namePieces[2];
     if (!output.servers[number]) 
        output.servers[number] = {};
     output.servers[number][name] = formData[x].value;
}
return output;
```